# How to iterate over array by key name and if keys are empty include them in loop js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have array like below:

```
{
  "": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "branch": null,
      "classification": null,
      "theme": null,
      "branch_id": null,
      "classification_id": null,
      "project_id": null,
      "theme_id": null,
      "projectname": "project tests",
      "comment": "commentsss",
      "customername": "alex",
      "lead1id": 2,
      "lead1percent": "2.0",
      "lead2id": 2,
      "lead2percent": "2.0",
      "lead3id": 2,
      "lead3percent": "3.0",
      "lead_plans": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "lead_id": 3,
          "addcosts": "3.0",
          "fee": "3.0",
          "plan2": "3.0",
          "plan3": "2.0",
          "probability": "3.0",
          "year": "2020-02-12"
        }
      ],
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "lead_id": 3,
          "addcosts": "2.0",
          "addcostsinfo": "some infoss",
          "days": "2020-02-12",
          "decision": "goodss",
          "decisiondate": "2020-02-12",
          "fee": "2.0",
          "mail": "mail goes here",
          "offerdate": "2020-02-12",
          "paper": "xyz"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "lead1percent": 2,
      "lead2percent": 2,
      "lead3percent": 3
    }
  ],
  "Electrical": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "branch": "Electrical",
      "classification": "Warm22",
      "theme": "Lean",
      "branch_id": 2,
      "classification_id": 1,
      "project_id": null,
      "theme_id": 3,
      "projectname": "TEST PROJECT",
      "comment": "",
      "customername": "tets cuso",
      "lead1id": 2,
      "lead1percent": "1.3",
      "lead2id": 16,
      "lead2percent": "4.5",
      "lead3id": 1,
      "lead3percent": "4.5",
      "lead_plans": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "lead_id": 4,
          "addcosts": "7.8",
          "fee": "5.6",
          "plan2": "2.3",
          "plan3": "3.4",
          "probability": "1.1",
          "year": "2020-05-10"
        },
        {
          "id": 35,
          "lead_id": 4,
          "addcosts": "6.9",
          "fee": "2.7",
          "plan2": "7.5",
          "plan3": "3.6",
          "probability": "1.7",
          "year": "2008-12-09"
        },
        {
          "id": 37,
          "lead_id": 4,
          "addcosts": "6.8",
          "fee": "2.7",
          "plan2": "8.3",
          "plan3": "1.9",
          "probability": "4.8",
          "year": "2001-12-07"
        }
      ],
      "offers": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "lead_id": 4,
          "addcosts": "8.6",
          "addcostsinfo": "TEST",
          "days": null,
          "decision": "TEST",
          "decisiondate": "2020-06-15",
          "fee": "2.4",
          "mail": "TEST",
          "offerdate": "2020-05-12",
          "paper": "TEST"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "lead1percent": 1.3,
      "lead2percent": 4.5,
      "lead3percent": 4.5
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want to iterate over it to do listing like below:

[image]

The code I was trying before is:

```
{
                                    leads_list.map((h, index) => {
                                        const lead_plans_totals = h.lead_plans.reduce(
                                            (accumulator, currentDau) => {
                                                return {
                                                    probability: accumulator.probability + parseFloat((currentDau.probability || 0)),
                                                    plan2: accumulator.plan2 + parseFloat((currentDau.plan2 || 0)),
                                                    plan3: accumulator.plan3 + parseFloat((currentDau.plan3 || 0))
                                                };
                                            }, {
                                                probability: 0,
                                                plan2: 0,
                                                plan3: 0
                                            }
                                        );

                                        const offers_totals = h.offers.reduce(
                                            (accumulator, currentDau) => {
                                                return {
                                                    addcosts: accumulator.addcosts + parseFloat((currentDau.addcosts || 0)),
                                                    fee: accumulator.fee + parseFloat((currentDau.fee || 0))
                                                };
                                            }, {
                                                addcosts: 0,
                                                fee: 0
                                            }
                                        );

                                        return <TableRow key={`mi-${index}`}
                                                         className={index % 2 == 0 ? 'grey_row' : ''}>
                                            <TableCell align="right" colSpan={2}>
                                                <IconButton onClick={() => this.launchEditLeadPlanOfferDialog(h)}>
                                                    <EditIcon/>
                                                </IconButton>
                                                <IconButton onClick={() => this.launchDeleteContactDialog(h.id)}>
                                                    <DeleteIcon/>
                                                </IconButton>
                                            </TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.projectno}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.customername}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.projectname}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.branch}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.theme}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.classification}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{lead_plans_totals.probability}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{lead_plans_totals.plan2}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{lead_plans_totals.plan3}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{offers_totals.addcosts}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{offers_totals.fee}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.lead1id}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.lead1percent}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.lead2id}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.lead2percent}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.lead3id}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.lead3percent}</TableCell>
                                            <TableCell align="right">{h.comment}</TableCell>
                                        </TableRow>
                                    })
                                }
```

Currently, with this above array it gives me error like:

```
TypeError: leads_list.map is not a function
LeadsSearchResults.render
src/container/Leads/LeadsSearchResults.js:397
  394 |         <TableCell align="right">Kommentar</TableCell>
  395 |     </TableRow>
  396 | </TableHead>
> 397 | <TableBody>
      | ^  398 |     {
  399 |         leads_list.map((h, index) => {
  400 |             const lead_plans_totals = h.lead_plans.reduce(
```

I tried using forEach too but similar results are coming up. I think the problem is that it contains empty key but I am not sure how to iterate them using keys and sum arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your data is an Object and not an array. You first need to get the keys and then you can map over it.

```
Object.keys(leads_list).map(key => {
    const h = leads_list[key][0];
    ... the rest of your code ...
});
```

Comment: It says: TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined

Comment: Looks like your items are wrapped in an array, I'll update the answer

Comment: But it does not appear to have the UI like I showed in image. How such UI can be made?

Comment: You need to style your components using css

Comment: Thank you I got it fixed based on your initial answer. I posted my answer and accepted yours as you deserve this rep!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Long answer,

I got the basic understanding and below is my final code.

I am going to accept his answer as it has given me right direction.

```
{
                                    Object.keys(leads_list).map((key, index) => {
                                        console.log(' KEY:::  ', key)
                                        console.log(' leads_list[key]:::  ', leads_list[key])

                                        return leads_list[key].map((h, index) => {
                                            console.log(' leads_lists::: if ', h)

                                            if (index < leads_list[key].length - 1) {

                                                const lead_plans_totals = h.lead_plans.reduce(
                                                    (accumulator, currentDau) => {
                                                        return {
                                                            probability: accumulator.probability + parseFloat((currentDau.probability || 0)),
                                                            plan2: accumulator.plan2 + parseFloat((currentDau.plan2 || 0)),
                                                            plan3: accumulator.plan3 + parseFloat((currentDau.plan3 || 0))
                                                        };
                                                    }, {
                                                        probability: 0,
                                                        plan2: 0,
                                                        plan3: 0
                                                    }
                                                );

                                                const offers_totals = h.offers.reduce(
                                                    (accumulator, currentDau) => {
                                                        return {
                                                            addcosts: accumulator.addcosts + parseFloat((currentDau.addcosts || 0)),
                                                            fee: accumulator.fee + parseFloat((currentDau.fee || 0))
                                                        };
                                                    }, {
                                                        addcosts: 0,
                                                        fee: 0
                                                    }
                                                );

                                                return (<TableRow key={`mi-${index}`}
                                                                  className={index % 2 == 0 ? 'grey_row' : ''}>
                                                    <TableCell align="right" colSpan={2}>
                                                        <IconButton
                                                            onClick={() => this.launchEditLeadPlanOfferDialog(h)}>
                                                            <EditIcon/>
                                                        </IconButton>
                                                        <IconButton
                                                            onClick={() => this.launchDeleteContactDialog(h.id)}>
                                                            <DeleteIcon/>
                                                        </IconButton>
                                                    </TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.projectno}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.customername}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.projectname}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.branch}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.theme}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.classification}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{lead_plans_totals.probability}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{lead_plans_totals.plan2}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{lead_plans_totals.plan3}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{offers_totals.addcosts}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{offers_totals.fee}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.lead1id}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.lead1percent}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.lead2id}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.lead2percent}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.lead3id}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.lead3percent}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.comment}</TableCell>
                                                </TableRow>)
                                            } else {
                                                console.log(' leads_lists::: else ', h)
                                                return (<TableRow>
                                                    <TableCell align="left"></TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="left" colSpan={7}>{key}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.lead1percent}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.lead2percent}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{h.lead3percent}</TableCell>
                                                </TableRow>)
                                            }
                                        })
                                    })
                                }
```